# What if RAII constructor throws?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a RAII class for fopen and fclose named ManagedFile and for some reason it fails and the constructor throws.

```
ManagedFile mf("e.txt") //fails and throws
mf.F( //What would happen here?9
```

Will mf never be created?

And if it won't, what happens if I use mf later, suppose to access file *F inside of mf?

What exactly happens if the constructor of a RAII class fails?

Comment: How is the constructor defined? Need some code.

Comment: How are you going to use `mf` if its constructor throws?

Comment: Also, how did you get 5k rep in 4 years without learning basic code formatting?  :/

Comment: how are you going to reach that line if it throws? unless you handle it inside (and then it does not)

Comment: @Augen that's exactly what I'm asking

Comment: Im on a cellphone right now and the cell keyboard is missing a lot of keys. i would have elaborated this queation more properly with code if i could

Comment: oh. so if the constructor fails that line will never be reached? i guess that has some implicationa thwn. well i guess i should delete this question and take a better look at the iasue when i get home

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the construction of `mf` fails, then the lifetime of `mf` will not be considered to have begun, any partial construction of `mf` will be reverted (by calling the destructors of bases and members that have completed their construction), and the following line, in which `mf` is used, will not be reached, since control will be transferred into a catch block (or the program will terminate).

Answer (score 5):

If a constructor throws (and the thrown exception is not caught in the constructor itself), the construction of the object fails.

If the class has class members, those class members would be fully constructed before the constructor executes, and a thrown exception will destroy them, before the thrown exception continues.

Ditto for any superclasses. The thrown exception will then also destroy any superclasses that were constructed prior to beginning of the construction of the subclass, and entering its constructor, where the exception got thrown.

The bottom line is that the object gets meticulously deconstructed, that is, whatever parts of it got already constructed, they'll get deconstructed.

In the end, the object cannot possibly exist anywhere. It is not logically possible for it to exist.

Since the exception was not caught, exception must propagate, and exit the scope in which the object was declared.

Even if you catch the exception:

```
 try
 {
       ManagedFile mf (  /* construct arguments */ );

       /* More code */
 } catch (...)
 {
     /* More code */
 }
```

This is the earliest place where you can possibly catch the exception. If it was thrown in `ManagedFile`'s constructor, execution cannot possibly continue inside the `try` block. You have to catch the exception, and this is the soonest that you can catch it.

And this `ManagedFile` object only exists inside the `try` block. Outside of the `try` block it doesn't exist. This includes the `catch` block. It doesn't exist there either.

So, if this constructor throws an exception, it will be logically impossible for the object to exist.

P.S. If the object was getting constructed in dynamic scope (with `new`), the thrown exception will also take care of releasing the memory that was allocated by `new`, before the exception propagates up the ladder.